# Microcast algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.x, mpi

Following is the main file in the project (executing tasks). It uses the `mpi4py` module, and multiple processes execute the same code. Please review the code and post your suggestions on making it more efficient and pythonic.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from Peers import Peers
from SegmentHandler import SegmentHandler
from Communicator import Communicator
import Message
import Datastore
import Queue
import random
import Logging


class JobScheduler:

    def __init__(self, environment):
        self.MAX_BACKLOG = 5
        self.SegmentAssignProcId = 0
        self.environment = environment
        self.segmentHandler = SegmentHandler()
        self.peers = Peers(self.environment.totalProc)
        self.dataHandler = Datastore.Datastore()

    def isSegmentAssigner(self):
        return self.environment.procId == self.SegmentAssignProcId

    def runMicroDownload(self):
        if self.isSegmentAssigner():
            self.microDownload()

    def initLocalQueue(self):
        self.toBeAdvertised = Queue.Queue()
        self.requestQueue = Queue.Queue()
        self.downloadRequests = Queue.Queue()

    def handleAdvertisementQueue(self):
        if not self.toBeAdvertised.empty():
            adMessage = self.toBeAdvertised.get()
            segmentId = adMessage.messageId
            Logging.logProcessOp(processId=self.environment.procId,
                                 op="pop",
                                 depQueue=self.toBeAdvertised,
                                 message=adMessage)
            reqMessage = adMessage.getResponse()

            # broadcast
            for _ in range(self.environment.totalProc):
                if _ != self.SegmentAssignProcId:
                    reqMessage.receiver = _
                    self.environment.send(_, reqMessage)

    def handleDownloadRequestQueue(self):
        if not self.downloadRequests.empty():
            dwnldReqMessage = self.downloadRequests.get()
            dwnldReqMessage.download()
            Logging.logProcessOp(processId=self.environment.procId,
                                 op="pop",
                                 depQueue=self.downloadRequests,
                                 message=dwnldReqMessage)
            self.dataHandler.addSegment(dwnldReqMessage.messageId,
                                        dwnldReqMessage.content)
            self.dataHandler.store(dwnldReqMessage)
            self.toBeAdvertised.put(dwnldReqMessage)
            # get response and send it to the inititor

    def handleRequestQueue(self):
        if not self.requestQueue.empty():
            reqMessage = self.requestQueue.get()
            responseMsg = reqMessage.getResponse()
            Logging.logProcessOp(processId=self.environment.procId,
                                 op="pop",
                                 depQueue=self.requestQueue,
                                 message=reqMessage)
            self.environment.send(responseMsg.receiver, responseMsg)

    def runMicroNC(self):
        if self.environment.procId != self.SegmentAssignProcId:
            self.microNC()

    def stopMicroNC(self):

        if self.toBeAdvertised.empty() and self.requestQueue.empty() and \
           self.downloadRequests.empty() and \
           self.dataHandler.downlodedAll(4):
            return True

        return False

    def microNC(self):

        Logging.logProcessOp(processId=self.environment.procId,
                             op="startMicroNC")

        self.initLocalQueue()

        while not self.stopMicroNC():

            nonDetchoice = random.randrange(4)

            if nonDetchoice == 0:

                _message = self.environment.nonBlockingReceive()

                if _message:
                    Logging.logChannelOp(_message.sender,
                                         _message.receiver,
                                         'receive',
                                         _message)

                    if isinstance(_message, Message.DownloadRequestMessage):
                        Logging.logProcessOp(processId=self.environment.procId,
                                             op="push",
                                             depQueue=self.downloadRequests,
                                             message=_message)
                        self.downloadRequests.put(_message)

                    if isinstance(_message, Message.AdvertisementMessage):
                        # request the sender for the segments
                        if not self.dataHandler.getSegment(_message.messageId):
                            _response = _message.getResponse()
                            Logging.logChannelOp(_message.sender,
                                                 _message.receiver,
                                                 'send',
                                                 _response)
                            self.environment.send(_response.receiver,
                                                  _response)

                    if isinstance(_message, Message.RequestMessage):
                        # add this to the request queue
                        Logging.logProcessOp(processId=self.environment.procId,
                                             op="push",
                                             depQueue=self.requestQueue,
                                             message=_message)
                        self.requestQueue.put(_message)

                    if isinstance(_message, Message.SegmentMessage):
                        Logging.logProcessOp(processId=self.environment.procId,
                                             op="receivedSegments")
                        self.dataHandler.addSegment(_message.messageId,
                                                    _message.content)
                        self.dataHandler.store(_message)

                    if isinstance(_message, Message.RequestResponseMessage):

                        assert(self.environment.processId ==
                               self.SegmentAssignProcId)

                        Logging.logProcessOP(processId=self.environment.procId,
                                             op="receivedDownloadConfirmation")

                        self.peers.removeBackLog(_message.sender)

                        if not _message.status:

                            self.segmentHandler.unassignSegment(
                                _message.messageId)

                            reqSegId = self.segmentHandler.getNextUnassigned()

                            requestSegment = RequestMessage(
                                self.SegmentAssignProcId,
                                reqSegId)

                            requestSegment.initMessage(
                                msgProperty=None,
                                msgContent=self.segmentHandler.getMetadata(
                                    reqSegId))

                            self.environment.send(feedback.fromId,
                                                  requestSegment)
                            self.segmentHandler.assignSegment(reqSegId)

            elif nonDetchoice == 1:
                self.handleRequestQueue()

            elif nonDetchoice == 2:
                self.handleDownloadRequestQueue()

            else:
                self.handleAdvertisementQueue()

    def microDownload(self):

        Logging.logProcessOp(processId=self.environment.procId,
                             op="startMicroNC")

        self.segmentHandler.downloadMetadata()
        self.peers.initPeers(self.environment.totalProc)

        while not self.segmentHandler.allAssigned():

            peerId = self.peers.leastBusyPeer()
            peerBackLog = self.peers.getBackLog(peerId)

            if peerBackLog < self.MAX_BACKLOG:

                requestSegmentId = self.segmentHandler.getNextUnassigned()
                requestSegment = Message.DownloadRequestMessage(
                    self.SegmentAssignProcId,
                    requestSegmentId,
                    peerId)
                requestSegment.initMessage(
                    msgProperty=None,
                    msgContent=self.segmentHandler.getMetadata(
                        requestSegmentId))

                self.environment.send(peerId, requestSegment)

                self.segmentHandler.assignSegment(requestSegmentId)
                self.peers.addBackLog(peerId)
                Logging.logChannelOp(chanFrom=self.SegmentAssignProcId,
                                     chanTo=peerId,
                                     op="send",
                                     message=requestSegment)

            else:
                Logging.info("Waiting for feedback")
```

Comment: Obligatory suggestion to follow [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (also, please review the indentation).